# include in result set columns the 5 returned columns in a User Defined Table Function

Tags: db2, user-defined-functions, db2-400, subquery

I have a UDTF that will always return 1 row of 6 columns
The UDTF has one parameter

I want the 5 columns included in the result set of a query.  The table I'm querying has a column that I want to use as the parameter for each row

I have not been able to figure out the correct syntax.

Any suggestions?

The UDTF

```
create function xxxx.UF_yyyyyy(USERID CHAR(10))
    returns table (
                p2User char(10),
                STATUS CHAR(3),
                USED DEC(7, 0),
                CREATED DEC(7, 0),
                SIGNON DEC(7, 0),
                EXCLUDE DEC(7, 0))
    language RPGLE
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
    DISALLOW PARALLEL
    NOT FENCED
    EXTERNAL NAME 'xxxx/UF_yyyyyy'
    PARAMETER STYLE DB2SQL
```

example

```
select * from table(xxxx/UF_yyyyyy(CHAR('CMFIRST   '))) a
```

result

```
 P2USER     STATUS USED    CREATED SIGNON  EXCLUDE
 ---------- ------ ------- ------- ------- -------
 CMFIRST    ACT    1170926 1150826 1170926       0
```

Here is an example of a select I tried

```
SELECT T1.AQABVN, T1.AQA8TX, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fffff T4 WHERE T4.BDABVN = T1.AQABVN) AS SACCMS,
        t2.p2User, t2.used
FROM  
    zzzzz T1 
    full join table(xxxx.UF_yyyyyy(T1.AQABVN)) t2 on T1.AQABVN = t2.p2User
```

Result

```
[SQL0205] Column P2USER not in table T2 in *N.
```

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, perhaps you could provide some sample data with sample results?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to create a view where the information fetched with a UDTF is included in the view columns.  The data fetched by the UDTF does not exist in a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working

```
SELECT T1.AQABVN, T1.AQA8TX, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fffff T4 WHERE T4.BDABVN = T1.AQABVN) AS SACCMS,
        t2.status, t2.used, t2.created, t2.signon, t2.exclude 
FROM  
  zzzzz T1 
    join 
  table(SMLFQA.UF_XAJKUPR(T1.AQABVN)) t2 on T1.AQABVN = t2.p2User
```

Comment: Glad to hear you found your answer.  Just remember that a UDTF appears in place of a table/view name.  So `JOIN table(SMLFQA.UF_XAJKUPR(T1.AQABVN))` instead of `JOIN mytable`